# Using AJAX and return a picture

Tags: html, ajax, blob

I have a problem receiving and opening a picture via AJAX.
If I call the following page:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8889/ex?sql=SELECT+Image+FROM+Persons+WHERE+Number+Like+%27%2501%27
```

a picture is displayed from a blob field in IE8.

Now I would like to open this into a div after someone pressed a key (using AJAX)?
Trying to use xhr.responseText does not work (I get an error. Using it on a text response works). So it seems that my problem is to grab the result from the ajax request.

How can I do this?

Some code and the error message:

```
var picReturn = xhr.responseText;
```

=> Could not continue due to the following error: c00ce514

Comment: Please, please, **PLEASE** don't tell me this is on a live site? What if I am looking for the image `DROP TABLE Persons`?

Comment: For less headache later on, use jQuery.

Comment: but that way I just load jquery for this one functionality. Somehow jquery needs to solve this too. And I would need to find out how jquery returns that picture to me.

By the way, why did you ask if this is on a life page?

Comment: Because passing and interpreting raw SQL using requests leaves you open to any number of possible attacks.

Comment: Ahh, that was your concern. No would not do this to open public stuff. But do you have any idea how to get the data. getAllResponseHeaders() shows that there are data. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

1. Place the resultant data in an iframe. Not very practical.
2. Take the result and place it in am image source as a data:uri.  Not supported in older browsers and limited to 32/64Kb depending on the browser.
3. Skip the AJAX and write a web service and use that as your url.  This is the best option.

You don't say what language you're using server-side but you essentially want to open a web response, set the header to "image/jpeg" and return your stream.

Comment: Thanks. How would I write a web service. Do you have a url where I can read how to start? The server-side only allows to send a few commands. One is to call /blobfield?sql=Select *...
Can you explain the web service a bit more?

Comment: What language is the backend?  PHP?  ASP.NET?  That method you highlighted is extremely dangerous.

Comment: PHP is the backend. For now its not about security. In a first step I would like to show a picture.

Comment: I'm not a PHP pro but you can use this as a starting point and modify it for your purposes.  You'll want to set the header to "image/jpeg" and echo the image.  http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json